# Javascript: Trouble with audio player, plays all audio at the same time

Tags: javascript, audio, ejs

I am trying to get this custom made audio player to work. The problem is when I press the play button for a certain mp3 player(which should play a singular mp3 file from the array), it plays all the songs in the array at the same time. And this happens for all the other mini mp3 players. 
Below is the .ejs file where I make an mp3 object for each song in the array

```
  <div class="container" id="mainBody">
   <div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <% songs.forEach(function(song){%>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="player">
                    <!--<div class="pl"></div>-->
                    <!--<div class="title"></div>-->
                    <div class="cover"></div>
                    <div class="bottom_section">
                        <div class= "controls">
                            ...play buttons go here...

                            ..js mp3 js file goes here right after..
```

My approach with this js script for each object with the class player (div="player"), I will declare the each song from the array as an audio track. The weird thing is each script that under each of these objects has their own separate audio tracks. But when I click play on any of the players, it plays all the files at once.

```
                 <% if(song) { %>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $(".player").each(function(index){
                                    var track = new Audio();
                                    track.src="<%=song%>";

                                    $(".mainB").click(function(){
                                        if(track.paused){
                                            track.play();
                                            $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-play fa fa-pause');
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            track.pause();
                                            $(this).toggleClass('fa fa-pause fa fa-play');
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            });

                        </script>
                    <% } %>
```

Im not really sure what im doing wrong. If anyone has any tips or suggestions I would really appreciate it!

Comment: This is probably because you have attached click handler too all button. I think it is better to attach click handler to parent node and then detect the event and play/pause accordingly.

Comment: thats a good point. im thinking of binding functions onto the button that is clicked but how would i refer to the parent button if i may ask? Im thinking using $(this "button class goes here").bind(class). Im currently trying it but im still running into problems

Answer (score 0):

May be create and audio element and style the controls using css. (If you want to further customize controls, remove the control attribute and add your own html controls and use JS to control it)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".player").each(function(i, el) {
    var track = document.createElement('audio');
    track.id = 'audio-player';
    track.controls = 'controls';
    track.src = '<%=song%>';
    track.type = 'audio/mpeg';
    el.appendChild(track);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Forgive me but can you explain further more what you mean? Everything else seams to make sense but Im a bit confused on the "track.controls = 'controls' " part and what you mean by styling that.

Comment: "track.controls = 'controls' " gives you the default html5 audio controls. If you want custom controls, you have to omit this line and implement your own.